# Global variable seems to update on its own

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, global-variables

Firstly, please be nice as I'm only getting started with [OpenCV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sTm9.jpg) in python and my python knowledge isn't spectacular.

I am trying to run OpenCV with numpy. I've made a white `canvas` where I keep track of the number of left-click events with `count`, so that I can

1. start drawing a circle with a mouseclick, or `cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN and count%2==1`
2. let the radius grow at mouse movement with `cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and count%2==0` (and **show the growing radius**)
3. permanently "print" the circle on a second click with `cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN and count%2==0`

Also, I have made two rectangles **blue** and **green** for color selection and I haven't allowed *starting* the circle within the bounds of these rectangles. Here, `canvas` is the continuously updated frame variable and `frame` is a matrix I use to refresh `canvas` when needed.

Now, in the output, when I drag my mouse, I expect the frames to refresh. So I let `canvas=frame`. In case of `cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN`, I instead set `frame=canvas` so that it saves the final output I want to keep in the output frame.

However, as you can see in the outputs:

1.[without clicking rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sTm9.jpg),

2.[touching green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shzyT.jpg) and

3.[touching both blue and green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrFAn.jpg)

it leaves a **trace** of the earlier frames(i.e it saves them to the frame). Not only that, I see the value of global variable frame changing **automatically** at `cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE` even though there isn't an assignment *to* `frame` in the callback function itself for that case! I see just one output with

> frame and canvas aren't equivalent

in my termninal,just after the first click.

I am using OpenCV's `setMouseCallback()` routine for the callback.

Can anyone guide me on what I'm doing wrong here? I know using global variables like this is taboo but I was only guided by some lectures I found.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

point=(0,0)
colour=(0,0,0)
line_width= 5
thickness=-1
count=1
radius=1
value=2**16-1
frame=value*np.ones((600,600,3),'uint16') 
canvas=value*np.ones((600,600,3),'uint16') 


def func(event,x,y,flags,param):
    
    global point,radius,line_width,thickness,colour,count,frame,canvas
    
    
    rect1=((x<=150 and x>=50) and (y>=50 and y<=150))
    rect2=((x>=200 and x<=300) and (y>=50 and y<=150))


    cv.rectangle(canvas,
    (50,50),
    (150,150),
    color=(2**16-1,0,0),
    thickness=-1)

    cv.putText(canvas,
    'Blue',
    fontFace=cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
    org=(70,70),
    fontScale=0.5,
    thickness=1,
    color=(0,0,0))

    cv.rectangle(canvas,
    (200,50),
    (300,150),
    color=(0,2**16-1,0),
    thickness=-1)

    cv.putText(canvas,
    'Green',
    fontFace=cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
    fontScale=0.5,
    thickness=1,
    org=(220,70),
    color=(0,0,0))
    

    
    
    if event==cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN and rect1:
        colour=(2**16-1,0,0)
    
    

    elif event==cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN and rect2:
        colour=(0,2**16-1,0)
            

    elif (event==cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) and count%2==1:
        point=(x,y)
        count=count+1

    elif event==cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and count%2==0:
        if not np.array_equiv(canvas,frame):
            print("frame and canvas aren't equivalent")
            canvas=frame                 
        radius=round(np.sqrt((x-point[0])**2+(y-point[1])**2))
        cv.circle(canvas, point, radius,colour,line_width)
        

    elif event==cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN and count%2==0:
        cv.circle(canvas, point, radius,colour,line_width)
        count=count+1
        frame=canvas       
    




cv.namedWindow("Frame")
cv.setMouseCallback("Frame",func)



while True:
    cv.imshow("Frame",canvas)
    ch=cv.waitKey(1)
    if ch & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv.imwrite("Img.jpg",canvas) 
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your code is a little hard to follow at the moment (it would be useful to isolate the problem using minimal code) but I guess you need to create a `deep copy` of your canvas/frame somewhere in your code. This behavior is typical of shallow arrays because their contents are shared amongst variables, instead of creating hard (deep) copies with their own data. If a variable modifies shared shallow data, all variables will reflect the modification.

Comment: When you do `canvas=frame`, both variables point to the same array. From this point onwards, you no longer have two arrays, just one array with two names.

Comment: don't worry about global variables. that's not the issue here. -- the window **only** updates when you call imshow. messing around with the array will not affect the window until you call imshow. -- you **are** allowed to call `imshow` from inside the on-mouse handler, and you should, to make this logic nice -- and what's with that counting logic? I don't see that being necessary. you have mouse-down, mouse-move, and mouse-up events. that is sufficient to store the mouse-down position, redraw the canvas upon every move, and finalize the whole thing on mouse-up

Comment: practically, you should keep one array that's representing the picture you paint, and in the event handler, when you are in the process of drawing a circle with the mouse, you copy that picture, draw the current "overlay" on the copy, and imshow it.

Comment: @stateMachine thank you so much for that. Didn't expect an OpenCV routine would force me to learn about python memory allocation, but it's great!

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you for your reply. I guess i was trying to do something else initially, but what you said sounds way cooler to do, and probably easier. I agree, counting isn't necessary for what you said. However, I can't figure how to register a single CLICK event, that is mouse-down, mouse-up event without using another local variable.

Comment: an "entire" click event (different from a drag-drop) _is_ composed of a mouse-down and a mouse-up **and** not too much movement between, so if you needed that, you would indeed need such logic.